# cannot add swap with fallocate on EC2

Tags: mount, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to setup the swap in `/etc/rc.local` this way:

```
sudo fallocate -l 8192M /mnt/swapfile1
sudo mkswap /mnt/swapfile1
sudo swapon /mnt/swapfile1
```

This however returns an error:

```
fallocate: /mnt/swapfile.sys: fallocate failed: Operation not supported
```

my partitions (EC2) are this:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-0-0-52:~$ df -h

Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1      7.8G  2.8G  4.6G  38% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            3.7G  8.0K  3.7G   1% /dev
tmpfs           752M  204K  752M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            3.7G     0  3.7G   0% /run/shm
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
/dev/xvdb       414G   71M  393G   1% /mnt
```

with `dd` it works, but it's kinda slow, I wanted to make sure swap is present on boot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of the Linux Kernel v2.6.31, the fallocate system call is supported by the btrfs, ext4, ocfs2, and xfs filesystems.

You can confirm which file system you have with this command (assuming the device name given above):

```
file -sL /dev/xvdb
```

Unfortunately, it appears that in some cases the instance storage is provided formatted at `ext3` instead of `ext4`.

Assuming your instance storage is at `/dev/svdb` and you want to make a swap file at `/mnt/swap` that's 16GB in size (huge!), Putting this is `/etc/rc.local` will make that happen every time at boot. You should comment out the line for `/dev/xvdb` in `/etc/fstab` in that case, because now the device will be mounted by `/etc/rc.local` late in the boot process instead of early.

`umount /dev/xvdb
mkfs.ext4  /dev/xvdb
mount /dev/xvdb /mnt
fallocate -l 16GB /mnt/swap
chmod 600 /mnt/swap
mkswap /mnt/swap
swapon /mnt/swap`